# How to enable and disable a button on form through dlookup function?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a query which shows a list of users and their access level which has tick box for the edit field.

The query shows the username, Form name and Edit field.

If the Edit field is ticked then I want the user to be able to click on the edit button and makes changes to the data on the form.

I have come up with this:

```
If (Dlookup("Edit", "QryUserAction", "UserName ="& Me!TempVars("UserName").[Value]  
And "FormName = "& Forms!Form.Name)) = False Then
    Forms!FrmPatientInfo!btnEdit.Enabled = False

Else
    Forms!FrmPatientInfo!btnEdit.Enabled = True
```

Comment: What does `not working` mean? Please provide the error or describe the misbehaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these should work. Your issue is you were not using the AND part of Dlookup correctly. The AND clause needs to be in quotes as it is part of the syntax. I also assume you left out the single quotes it requires for string values.

Side note - having a control to store UserName is bad practice - there is the environ function which can get you the user name. Unless the user's logging is different than whats store din the db, this should be sufficient

```
If (Dlookup("Edit", "QryUserAction", "UserName ='" & Me!TempVars("UserName").[Value] & "' And FormName = '" & Me.Name & "'")) = False Then
    Forms!FrmPatientInfo!btnEdit.Enabled = False
Else
    Forms!FrmPatientInfo!btnEdit.Enabled = True
End if

If (Dlookup("Edit", "QryUserAction", "UserName ='" & ENVIRON("USERNAME") & "' And FormName = '" & Me.Name & "'")) = False Then
    Forms!FrmPatientInfo!btnEdit.Enabled = False
Else
    Forms!FrmPatientInfo!btnEdit.Enabled = True
End if
```